# default namespace for an ASP.NET project in vs2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am working on a asp.net web app in visual studio team system 2008 (visual web developer 2008) (version 9.0.21022.8) (.NET 3.5 sp1).
I'm trying to figure out how to add a "default" namespace to this project.

I don't see any where in the properties that even references namespaces.
I know in VS 2010 there is a properties dialog box, but I can't find it in VS 2008.

I've been Googling all day and can't find anything relating to this.
What I have run across there appears to be this option, but no directions how to get to that screen.

Comment: You sure you aren't using a "web site" instead of a "Web Application"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are working on a Web Site project rather than a Web Application project.

Web sites do not have a default namespace (as other .Net projects have), and the page classes are in the global namespace. Code-behind files do not contain a namespace declaration, and markup references the classes without a namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the project in solution explorer. Open up properties. Then under the application tab you should see a Default Namespace field in which you can enter your default namespace.

Comment: this is not present in a website project